# Connect to VPN using python pip install package error

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the error that appears:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 140, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 128, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 29, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 272, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 851, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 798, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 758, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 490, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 400, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 115, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 454, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 532, in request
    settings = self.merge_environment_settings(
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 711, in merge_environment_settings
    env_proxies = get_environ_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 797, in get_environ_proxies
    if should_bypass_proxies(url, no_proxy=no_proxy):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 781, in should_bypass_proxies
    bypass = proxy_bypass(parsed.hostname)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 102, in proxy_bypass
    return proxy_bypass_registry(host)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 89, in proxy_bypass_registry
    if re.match(test, host, re.I):
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 190, in match
    return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\re.py", line 303, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 511, in _parse
    sourceget()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 256, in get
    self.__next()
  File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python310\lib\sre_parse.py", line 245, in __next
    raise error("bad escape (end of pattern)",
re.error: bad escape (end of pattern) at position 12
```

There has been no solution, and I specially registered an account to ask questions.

At first I installed python10 in the same folder as python9. The error reported that the pip version is not new enough. I have upgraded the pip version and the python version successively through the search engine, but it has not been resolved. Then I saw that turning off the VPN can be used normally. I want to know how to install the package without turning off the VPN, because the installation will be very slow without using the VPN, and I have to actively turn off the VPN every time I install it.

Comment: what did you run to cause this issue?

Comment: In cmd, pip install <package name>.
He is normal if not connected to VPN. I try to download from pypi.org, even if connected to VPN, it can be downloaded

Comment: is it any package at all?

Comment: Several commonly used packages I have tried so far are like this